# Reinstalling or resetting Windows 10 using the cloud when MBR corrupted

Tags: windows-10, boot, mbr

I have seen in many links that Windows 10 can be reinstall or reset using cloud.

Can it be done, when MBR is corrupted?

When MBR gets corrupted, most of time we get puzzled in various steps.

However, in some cases, we’re not able to resolve the issue.

Moreover, in some cases, we don’t have additional computer and flash drive so that bootable flash drive can be created and windows fresh installation can be done.

That's why please let me know, can Windows 10 be installed or reset with cloud, if MBR gets corrupted?

If it can’t be done by default, can it be enabled? If yes, please let me know how?

Best Regards

FewL

Answer (score 5):

When your MBR (Master Boot Record) is corrupted, your computer's BIOS can't find your Windows partition and boot so it is unlikely that even if there was an option to reset in the cloud, you would be able to do it. Your best bet is to use WinRE if possible, to try and repair the MBR. What do you mean by resetting Windows from the cloud? If you mean resetting Windows remotely, that depends on your security settings. If your MBR gets corrupted and you can access WinRE or a repair disk by your OEM and use `chkdsk`, `bootrec /fixmbr`, `bootrec /fixboot`, and `bootrec /rebuildbcd`. These commands don't have to be tried in that order, but they are all available in WinRE/WinPE to help fix your MBR or BCD. Check out [this link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/927392/use-bootrec-exe-in-the-windows-re-to-troubleshoot-startup-issues) for more on `bootrec`. Also, you can use WinRE to reset Windows if needed.